# Postgres ltree doesn't use Gist index Why?

Tags: postgresql, ltree

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy_table(id integer PRIMARY KEY,path ltree);

INSERT INTO hierarchy_table
VALUES (1, '1'),
(2,'1.2'),
(3,'1.2.3'),
(4,'1.2.4'),
(5,'1.5'),
(6,'1.5.6'),
(7,'1.5.7'),
(8,'1.5.8');   

CREATE INDEX idx_hierarchy_table_gist ON hierarchy_table USING gist(path);


explain analyze select * from hierarchy_table where '1.2' @> path
```

Result:

> Seq Scan on hierarchy_table (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=1 width=36) (actual
> time=0.009..0.011 rows=3 loops=1)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6e363/2

Comment: For a tiny table like that, using an index won't make things faster to begin with

Comment: Why would it? It would take longer to do the lookup in the index and use that to find the rows in the table  then to just do the `Seq Scan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table with 8 rows is pointless to index, and pointless to test with.

Comment: You have right, if I create index before inserts then use index, but after ANALYZE doesn't! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have observered, if I have created gist index before inserts it works with index.

But so the recreate index is dangerous :)